# Importing data with React - why is this not working?

Tags: reactjs, import, react-context

Can anyone tell me why this is not working?  I've scoured the resources I can find, and it all looks the same as the model I'm following, but the "import ProductData" statement does not seem to be working.  If I set a breakpoint at the first line after the import, "ProductData" is undefined.  I'm stumped.

Here is the code in the file named "ProductContext.js":

```
import { useState, createContext } from "react";
import ProductData from "../../Data/ProductData";

const ProductContext = createContext();

export const ProductProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [ProductList, setProductList] = useState(ProductData);

    return (
        <ProductContext.Provider
            value={ ProductList }
        >
            {children}
        </ProductContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default ProductContext;
```

And here is the code from my "ProductData.js" file:

```
const ProductData = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "item 1",
        "image": "1.jpg",
        "price": 9.99,
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "item 2",
        "image": "2.jpg",
        "price": 199.99,
    },
    ...
];

export default ProductData;
```

Comment: const ProductContext = createContext(ProductData);  //add this line

Comment: Thank you Naveen - that got me a big step closer.  Still didn't work as expected until I changed a line in my Products.js component, from "const { ProductList } = useContext(ProductContext);" to "const ProductList = useContext(ProductContext);
" (removed brackets around the ProductList variable).  I don't understand why this is the case, as the model I was following had the brackets in the same place and worked just fine.  At any rate, it is working now, and I thank you for your help!